# operacion con strings js

Tags: javascript

una consulta, tengo que escribir una función "longitudNombreCompleto" que tome un nombre y un apellido como parametro y devuelva su longitud total, contando un espacio extra para separar a ambos.

```
function longitudNombreCompleto
    var a="nombre";
    var b="apellido";
longitudNombreCompleto.length = (a+b);
```

esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora, pero no me termina de cerrar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function longitudNombreCompleto(nombre, apellido) {
  return nombre.length + apellido.length + 1
}
```

El "+ 1" es para sumarle el carácter espacio que supuestamente les separa.

Answer (score 3):

Para calcular la longitud deberías obtener la propiedad lenght de a + " " + b.

```js
function longitudNombreCompleto() {
    var a = "nombre";
    var b = "apellido";
    console.log((a + " " + b).length);
}
longitudNombreCompleto();
```

Comment: No puede ser que hallamos pensado exactamente lo mismo al mismo tiempo... ._. borrare mi respuesta, puesto que tu colocaste exactamente lo que iba a colocar primero xd.

Comment: Era un problema bastante limitado jeje. Muchas gracias, acabo de empezar a colaborar y me gusta ver que hay más gente que piensa como yo a la hora de realizar las soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar los caracteres de un nombre y apellido, con espacio.

```
function longitudNombreCompleto(nombre, apellido){
let longitud = nombre+" "+apellido;
return longitud.length; 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Por favor revisa [answer] y antes de responder a una pregunta revisa si por casualidad tiene o no respuestas válidas de modo que puedas determinar si la tuya hace algún aporte significativo. En este caso **duplicas casi sin cambio** lo que se respondió hace casi un año.